# find the percentage share of each language from the a month of 30 days: getting errors

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I used [this MySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaahG.png).

I am trying to find the percentage share of each language over the course of 30 days from it.

```
select language as languages, round(100*count(*)/total, 2)
from job_data
cross join (select count(*) as total from job_data) sub
group by language;
```

[The error is highlighted in the 'Output' tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgxqp.png)

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Language, COUNT(job_id) AS num_jobs
    FROM job_data
    WHERE event IN("transfer","decision")
    AND ds >= "2020-11-01" AND  ds <= "2020-11-30"
    GROUP BY language),
total AS (
    SELECT COUNT(job_id) AS total_jobs
    FROM job_data
    WHERE event IN("transfer","decision")
    AND ds >= "2020-11-01" AND  ds <= "2020-11-30"
    GROUP BY language)
SELECT language, ROUND(100.0*num_jobs/total_jobs, 2) AS perc_jobs
FROM CTE
ORDER BY perc_job DESC;
```

> `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'total_jobs' in 'field list'`

I understood the error I got while I tried the second method.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: There is no question in this post. Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question about 1 problem. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please format code reasonably. Please don't just dump a bunch of wrong code or say you had some. Please don't tell a story about things you tried. Ask about 1 bad query or give working relevant parts & no bad code & ask about how you think they could go together for your goal. Put everything needed to ask in your post with credit & relate to your question. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions:

```
select language, count(*) cnt, count(*) / sum(count(*)) over() ratio
from job_data 
where event in ('transfer', 'decision') 
    and ds >= '2020-11-01' 
    and ds <  '2020-12-01'
group by language
```

This aggregates your table by language, then computes the counts; expression `sum(count(*)) over()` computes the total of all counts - you can use it as a denumerator of the division.

Notes:

- window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only
- use single quotes rather than double quotes for literal strings (and dates); this followos the SQL standard, which all databases support
- I would recommend filtering dates with half-open intervals rather than `between` (that typically works better if your dates have a time portion)

Answer (score -2):

```
select language, count(distinct language),
    round(100*count(*)/(select count(*) from job_data),2) as percentage_share
from job_data
group by language order by language desc;
```

Comment: Please explain how this addresses the probem, code-only answers are poor. [answer] [Help] Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please format code reasonably. Please use code format for code & only code & quote format for & only for quotes, etc.